# How to remove storybook from the react project

Tags: reactjs, uninstallation, storybook

How to uninstall storybook from the react project ?
what is the command should I've to use to uninstall storybook?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

**They don't have a cli command to automate this.**
Follow the following steps to remove storybook from your project

- delete your stories
- delete the .storybook folder
- delete the scripts added to package.json
- delete all storybook related dependencies from package.json
- run `yarn` or `npm install` to update the lockfile

Storybook doesn't know where your stories are until runtime, so it's hard to know exactly what to delete. Also users sometimes have multiple storybooks in 1 repo, so overall it's rather complicated. Adding files is usually safer then removing... we might remove something that the user can't recover from.

[Here is a full discussion on github](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/979)

Comment: On last step, run `npm install` instead of update.

Comment: Wouldn't it be `npm rm` (remove) instead?

Comment: Also if you use eslint, you'll want to remove the storybook plugin from .eslintrc.json.  And the first point above "delete your stories".  It's not just *your* stories, Storybook itself installs some sample stories into the stories directory so delete the entire stories directory.

Comment: You can use the find command to delete all matching files. `find ./path/to/current/project -name '*.stories.js' -delete`