# How can I resolve this issue about Storybook and Sass?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, sass, storybook

I have an issue about Storybook. I can't start storybook and I have an error about my SCSS file.

Here is the error:

> ModuleParseError: Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
> You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> .h1 {
> |   color: red;
> | }
> at handleParseError (/myproject/node_modules/@storybook/builder-webpack4/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:469:19)

I mean this is juste a simple class. But when the file is empty, the compilation is okay, so I don't understand how I can resolve this.

My SCSS file

```
.h1 {
  color: red;
}
```

My Webpack file

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/index.js'),
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ['babel-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/i,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: '[path][name].[ext]',
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx'],
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
  plugins: [new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()],
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    hot: true,
  },
};
```

My main.js file in the .storybook folder

```
module.exports = {
  "stories": [
    "../src/**/*.stories.mdx",
    "../src/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)",
    "../src/**/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)"
  ],
  "addons": [
    "@storybook/addon-links",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials"
  ]
}
```

Is anyone has a solution please?
Thanks by advance

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I have solved my problem, so here is how I did it.

First of all, I uninstalled the storybook ([How to remove storybook from the react project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68062232/how-to-remove-storybook-from-the-react-project)), then the reinstalled via webpack (https://storybook.js.org/blog/storybook-for-webpack-5/).
For once with Webpack it works whereas installing it with NPM (or Yarn for my part) brought me to the complications that I had posted above. My guess is that it works for Webpack 5, whereas with NPM, I was getting an error about the css-loader loader that told me about Webpack 4.

Storybook worked, but I was still worried about `.scss` files. My terminal told me that I did not have a specific loader. So I took a loader for this type of file by adding a `webpack.config.js` in the `.storybook` folder created when we install Storybook. I used the instructions found here: https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/configure/webpack

About Sass files: Storybook is case sensitive, and also doesn't take into account files starting with `_`, so not possible to use partials

I hope you don't have this kind of problem, but if you do, maybe these answers will help you ^^

Answer (score 0):

For me, I did not have to follow the steps above, but I did need to adjust my import statement in `preview.ts` to read as follows:

```
import '!style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader!../src/scss/app.scss';
```

Comment: Did you need to install the packages: `!style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader!` ?